# Caml Query returning null

Tags: sharepoint-2013, web-parts, caml, sharepointdocumentlibrary

I was trying to retrieve documents from document library using CAML Query, but this query returns null. Please help to solve this.

```
SPDocumentLibrary oDocumentLibrary = (SPDocumentLibrary)oWebsite.Lists["SampleDocument"];

SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
query.Query = string.Format("<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Author' /><Value Type='Text'>Name</Value></Eq></Where>");
SPListItemCollection collListItems = oDocumentLibrary.GetItems(query);

DataTable dt = collListItems.GetDataTable();
```

Comment: I'd recommend trying on [SharePoint Stack Exchange](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/) for SharePoint-specific questions. Might be a better concentration of SharePoint-developers.

Answer (score 0):

You can check `Caml` query in `Caml Designer` if the query is returning exact result or not.

Try with `Camlex` add CamlexNET using Nuget

```
using CamlexNET;
var caml = Camlex.Query().Where(x => ((string)x["Author"] == "Value").ToString();
var query = new SPQuery
{
     Query = caml,
     RowLimit = 5000
};

SPList list = web.Lists["Document"];
SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);

foreach (SPListItem itm in items)
{
   //var id = Convert.ToString(itm["ID"]);
}
```